# manipulate the view of firefox from extern

Tags: python, linux, firefox, sh

I need to extend a given project. I couldn’t find an ideal solution yet which is why I seek help here.
On a PC with Linux Firefox is running in fullscreen mode and constantly shows the content of an external page. The deomen caring for Firefox looks approximately like this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export START_REMOTE_CONTROL=1

startproc -s -l /dev/null -u A_USER -g A_GROUP  /PATH_TO_FIREFOX/firefox -private -url www.EXTERNAL_PAGE.com -fullscreen
```

Additionally there is a admin-tool running on the pc implemented as Python Django website. Over the offered site people can log on to the local network and administer some things.

What is supposed to be added now:
At a certain action a site provided by the Django webserver (localhost/SPECIAL_PAGE) should be shown temporarily (till turned off again) in the mentioned firefox. 
This should be realized with as little changes as possible.

I haven’t got any influence on the standard site (in the example www.EXTERNAL_PAGE.com ). So I can’t implement any javascript creating a websocket to Python Webserver which I could use to say: „Now load the content from localhost/SPECIAL_PAGE."
One idea I had was with Firefox and the Django webserver running on the same pc, the Django webserver getting the order could open a new tab using a shell command with localhost/SPECIAL_PAGE.
This site requests every half a second via Ajax if the special mode has been disabled.
If so the tab gets closed via Javascript and the original state is regained.

I tried on my own pc if this would work. It  did the trick but I noticed the following: Javascript isn’t allowed to close tabs it hasn’t opened itself. None of the workarounds I could find on the web did work on my version.
Anyway I did find out that it does work if the settings dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows are set to true. But that’s no good solution because the external site could exploit the situation. 
But if there is no solution more elegant to be found I could accept this.

Anyway I now tried it at the project PC using the admin website. To put it short: It didn’t work out.

The code I used to try to open the tab inside the Django Webserver is:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["/PATH_TO_FIREFOX/firefox", "-new-tab",  "localhost/SPECIAL_PAGE"])
```

I think it might have something to do with Firefox getting started by a Deomon and that thereby the access might be different (-u A_USER und  -g A_GROUP is identical in calling the Firefox or the Django webserver).

Does anybody know what’s the mistake?
Or can anybody even imagine a more elegant solution?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

starting the firefox session via [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) would grant you full control over the firefox session while it is running
for example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

using a [custom profile](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks) and running a python script (or django server) on the machine that launches the web browser should enable you to accomplish everything you're trying to do

Comment: Thank you for the informations. But I want to avoide new software. But ff we don't find an other solution, i can try it.